# shared_ptr throwing assert when it goes out of scope

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

Ok, I've been trying to wrap my head around this for some time now , but I dont get it can someone please tell me why case#1 throws an assert (BLOCK TYPE IS INVALID)?

case #1

```
mehodName()
{
    // Get all dependents for this resource
    boost::shared_ptr<std::set<std::string>> dependents = deactivatedResource->getDependendents();
    // Do some stuff 
} // Assertion thrown here (heap gets corrupted)
```

Here's the  getDependents in this case :

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::set<std::string>> Resource::getDependendents()
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<std::set<std::string>>(&dependents);
}
```

case #2

```
mehodName()
{
// Get all dependents for this resource
std::set<std::string>* dependents = deactivatedResource->getDependendents();
} // No problem !! (but an obvious leak , if I try to use delete ,then the same assertion as in case 1)
```

Here's the  getDependents in this case :

```
   std::set<std::string>* Resource::getDependendents()
   {
    return &dependents;
   }
```

For both cases :

```
std::set<std::string> dependents;
```

Comment: What does `getDependents` actually return (i.e., what does the definition of that function do)?  Why are you not using smart pointers consistently?

Comment: The corruption happens before your shared_ptr goes out of scope. Use some memory checked like valgrind

Comment: Probably you are misunderstanding the ownership semantics of `getDependents`. Check the documentation and/or the code.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Edited question , I am using it consistently , used the naked pointer because the shared_ptr was giving the assertion failure.

Comment: @KerrekSB I wrote that method

Comment: @VJovic I have actually stepped through the code and verified the integrity of data upto that exact point.

Comment: @angryInsomniac: in that case, you haven't thought well enough about the ownership semantics of that function. Design it cleanly and don't leave anything ambiguous. Look at the source, think.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That overtly sarcastic statement indicates to me that there is something very obviously wrong here , could you please enlighten me ?

Comment: @angryInsomniac Sorry for the sarcasm, it’s uncalled for. This code is just so very obviously wrong, considering what `shared_ptr` does.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I dont disagree that it is wrong , that much is obvious, but I am forced again , to ask the same question , how , is it so "obviously" wrong !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is it `dependents` an attribute of `Resource`?, it seems that boost is trying to deallocate non-dynamic memory when the reference gets to zero. You could return a reference in that case.
2. is it dependents a local variable? if so you should use dynamic memory.

Update:

Then in your case it doesn't make sense returning a shared pointer as the object `dependents` has not been created dynamically.

In any case, if you would need to create it dynamically, you should do the following:

In the class declaration:

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::set<std::string> > dependents;
```

In the constructor:

```
Constructor (...) : dependents (new std::set<std::string> ()) { ... }
```

But in your case there is no need to use dynamic memory. I would recommend you to return a reference rather than a pointer.

Answer (score 6):

`shared_ptr` manages resource ownership. When you pass it a pointer you’re effectively saying “this is yours. Make sure you dispose of it when you go out of scope.”<sup>1</sup>

But then you pass it a pointer that mustn’t be disposed since it’s pointing to an object with automatic storage. This doesn’t work. Only use `shared_ptr` on pointers that have been created using `new`.<sup>2</sup>

As a consequence, the `shared_ptr` is trying to `delete` a resource that hasn’t been `new`ed. This causes the error you observe.

---

<sup>1</sup> That’s a simplification. Actually, `shared_ptr` manages *shared* ownership (= shared with other `shared_ptr` instances); this means that the resource will only be disposed of once *all* owning `shared_ptr`s have gone out of scope.

<sup>2</sup> Also a simplification: there are other ways than `new` of obtaining resources that need to be managed, but then you need to tell `shared_ptr` *how* to manage the resource. The default disposing action is `delete`, which only works on `new`ed resources.

Comment: The guys in the c++ chat seem to think otherwise ! and as the name says , one stands to reason that the pointer is shared !

Comment: @angryInsomniac See update. I was (intentionally) oversimplifying but then I realised that a clarification was needed.

Comment: Ref#1 If it manages shared ownership and this object is owned elsewhere as well , then why is this context trying to delete it ?

Comment: @angryInsomniac Good comment. `shared_ptr`s only track shared ownership among other instances of `shared_ptr`, not across the whole type system (the latter would require “magic” in C++ since C++ has no way of knowing where a pointer comes from).

Comment: Hmm , so basically that means that the problem stems from dependents being a member variable and not a shared pointer in its own right.

Comment: @angryInsomniac Yes. In your case, the memory is actually owned and managed by the object that this variable belongs to. You can’t take that ownership away.

Comment: Heres the funny part, when I make it a shared_ptr , there is an assert failure in the shared_ptr.hpp file !

Comment: @angryInsomniac: Why is that funny?

Comment: @CharlesBailey I find causing errors in the header files quite funny, don't you ?

Comment: @angryInsomniac: Perhaps it's just my warped sense of humour, but no, I really don't see why it would be funny.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for the help , that helped me clarify some stuff , but I feel that changing the method to return a reference would be much better for this situation

Comment: Returning a reference does seem like the ideal solution.  If for some reason you MUST have a pointer, the last resort is simply to return a raw pointer to the "dependents" object.

Comment: @angryInsomniac Hard to say from the outside … in particular, how long does the original object persist? If it persists long enough then yes, returning a reference is probably the best solution.